# Export-csv doesnt give me the data I'm expecting

Tags: powershell

When I run the code below the data I get in the csv doesn't have the server names I'm expecting.

Instead this is what I get in the .csv file

```
Length
204
```

Why is this?

```
$varoutfile = "\\unc_path\server $(get-date -f yyyy-MM).csv"
$varDOW = (get-date).DayOfWeek
$varservertoreboot = "server1" , "server2" , "server1" , 

if ($varDOW -eq "Sunday") {
    foreach ($server in $varservertoreboot) {
        Restart-Computer $varservertoreboot -Force
        "$(get-date -f yyyy-MM-dd-HH-mm-ss) Today is $vardow, The system 
        $varservertoreboot is rebooting" | Export-Csv $varoutfile -Append -NoClobber -NoTypeInformation 
    }
}
else {}

if ($varDOW -eq "Wednesday") {
    foreach ($server in $varservertoreboot) {
        Restart-Computer $varservertoreboot -Force
        "$(get-date -f yyyy-MM-dd-HH-mm-ss) Today is $vardow, The system $varservertoreboot is rebooting" | Export-Csv $varoutfile -Append -NoClobber

    }
}
```

Comment: You probably mean `Out-File`, not `Export-Csv`. You're adding raw strings, `Export-Csv` tries to deconstruct object properties into columns. Of course, `String` has no meaningful properties (other than `Length`), so that's what you get.

Comment: Thank you. I'll give that a try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd replace:

```
"$varservertoreboot is rebooting" | Export-Csv $varoutfile -Append -NoClobber -NoTypeInformation

"$(get-date -f yyyy-MM-dd-HH-mm-ss) Today is $vardow, The system $varservertoreboot is rebooting" | Export-Csv $varoutfile
```

With:

```
Add-Content -Value "$varservertoreboot is rebooting" -Path $varoutfile

Add-Content -Value "$(get-date -f yyyy-MM-dd-HH-mm-ss) Today is $vardow, The system $varservertoreboot is rebooting" -Path $varoutfile
```